# Send Google Analytics Data to eCommerce Server

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, google-analytics, e-commerce

We want to save in our database (custom-developed shop with C# and ASP.NET) where our customers came from to improve our marketing strategies, so:

Is it possible to send google analytics data to the eCommerce server while performing a checkout?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the ecommerce option on your google analytics dashboard.
Then, enter the tracking code on the purchase confirmation page.

You can consult the link below:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009612?hl=en

It is also possible to identify the user's origin to improve their marketing campaigns. Just follow this:

- https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033173?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

The **[Real Time Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3)** enables you to request real time data—for example, real time activity on your property.

However you can extract information such as pages and events, not ecommerce data. Therefore you should make sure to track the checkout funnel so that the information is within an event (with category, action and label). At that point you can use the API I indicated.